# Reflection matrix of even dimension with $\det f= -1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a Euclidean vector space with an even dimension and 
$f: V \to V$ an orthogonal mapping with  $\det f= -1$.

Is it right, that $f$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$?
because of $| \lambda |= 1$.
The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, therefore there must be at least one $-1$.

Can you show me the proof that the eigenvalues of $f$ are $1$ and $-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your argument is broken(*). That the eigenvalues can be nothing else than $1$ and $-1$ follows from the orthogonality of $f$ and **not** the determinant being $-1$. That it actually has these eigenvalues follows from the determinant and even dimension.

Suppose that we have an eigenvector $u\ne0$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then we have since inner product is preserved

$$\lambda^2 \langle u, u\rangle = \langle \lambda u,\lambda u\rangle = \langle fu, fu\rangle = \langle u, u\rangle$$

That is $\lambda^2 = 1$.

One can also show that since $\det f=-1$ that there exists eigenvalues. This is because the degree of the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ must be the same as the dimension of the space. You also have that $\det f = p(0) = -1$. Also we have that the highest order term of the polynomial (of even exponent) has coefficient $1$ that is the polynomial is of the form: So we have that $\lim_{\lambda\to\pm\infty} p(\lambda) = \infty$ so we have that $p(\lambda) has at least one positive and one negative root.

Also we can always construct the case where the multiplicity of these eigenvalues are only $1$. We do this by using rotations in pairwise dimensions, that is:

$$f = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 &   &   & \cdots \\
 0 & 1 &   &   & \cdots \\
   &   & 0 & -1 &       \\
   &   & 1 &  0 & \ddots \\
\vdots & \vdots & &\ddots & \ddots  
\end{pmatrix}$$

that is the second block repeats. One can see that the characteristic polynomial here is $(-1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2+1)^{n-1}$.

(*) An example when your reason fails is the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  0  & 0 & 0\\
0  & -2 & 0 &0  \\
0  &  0  & 0 & -1/2 \\
0  &  0  & 1/2 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

which isn't orthogonal. It's characteristic polynomial is $(2-\lambda)(-2-\lambda)(\lambda^2+1/4)$ so the eigenvalues are $\lambda = \pm2$, but it's determinant is $1$ (which isn't the product of the eigenvalues).

Comment: But that one has determinant $1$, not $-1$.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer - the determinant being $-1$ is useful to show that it actually has the eigenvalues $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, real linear operators can have complex eigenvalues, and if you want to not consider those (which is reasonable because they don't have corresponding eigenvectors in your real vector space) then the determinant is not in general the product of all eigenvalues. (In case of a real orthogonal operator there is an additional condition that the eigenvalues (the multi-set of roots of the characteristic polynomial) are both concentrated on the unit circle (the $|\lambda|=1$ condition) and symmetric under complex conjugation, which means that non-real eigenvalues come in pairs whose product is $1$, so the determinant ends up also being the product of the *real* eigenvalues, all $1$ or $-1$. But just saying "the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues" strongly suggests you did not make this reasoning to arrive at the conclusion.)

So for instance a plane rotation is real orthogonal but has no real eigenvalues at all. Add an orthogonal eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$ (giving a roto-reflection) and you have determinant $-1$; you now have odd dimension, so if you want to have even dimension you must also add an eigenvector for $\lambda=1$.

Returning to your question, I am not sure I answered it, because I'm not sure what is being asked.

Comment: "...for instance a rotation is real orthogonal but has no real eigenvalues at all" isn't true? Rotations have an eigenvalue of +1, consider a vector along axis of rotation?

Comment: @PM. I meant rotations in the plane. But I'll correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that all the eigenvalues of $f$ are either $1$ or $-1$. The **real** eigenvalues are. For instance, the eigenvalues of the orthogonal matrix $$f=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0&0\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\\\end{pmatrix}$$
are: $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta,\ \cos\theta-i\sin\theta,\ 1,\ -1$.

For a real matrix, though, a complex eigenvalue $z$ with $\Im z\ne 0$ appears with the same algebraic and geometric multiplicities of $\overline z$, thus $$\det f=\left(\prod_{\omega\in\Bbb R\cap\operatorname{Eig}f} \omega^{m_{\text{alg}}(\omega)}\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{\omega\in\operatorname{Eig}f,\ \Im\omega>0} \lvert\omega\rvert^{2m_{\text{alg}}(\omega)}\right)$$

So, indeed, a real matrix $f$ with $\det f<0$ must have *at least* one real negative eigenvalue.

Comment: Dimension $3$ is not an even dimension, is it?

Comment: @celtschk Of course: for some reason I was thinking of odd order. Now I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of a real matrix, when considered as complex matrix all of whose entries happen to be real, either are real themselves, or come in complex conjugated pairs.

Since the determinant is the product of all eigenvalues, due to the conjugated pair property any complex eigenvalue $\lambda$ gives rise to the factor $\lambda\overline \lambda = \left|\lambda\right|^2>0$, this it in particular cannot change the sign of the determinant. Therefore any real matrix with negative determinant must have at least one negative real eigenvalue. Note that this is true independent of any other properties of the matrix.

On the other hand, the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix have absolute value $1$. Now the only negative real number with absolute value $1$ is $-1$, therefore a real orthogonal matrix of negative determinant (and therefore determinant $-1$) always has at least one eigenvalue $-1$.

Note that this is independent of dimension, that is, it holds both in even and odd dimensions.